# Trigger transition to do replaceState rather than pushState

Tags: react-router

I am building a component that dis displaying a table of data. As they add and remove filters to that data, I would like modify the queryString with replaceState, but as far as I can see there is no method to do that.

Is there a way to tell the transition to use replaceState rather than pushState?

Comment: Can you provide some code examples of what you've got in place already?

Comment: Not exactly because I don't even see anything specific to try. I have only played with the basic Link component provided in the library, but looking through the [doc itself](http://rackt.github.io/react-router/) I don't see anything.

Comment: So basically on page events you want to update the url state without using a `Link`, right?

Comment: Whether or not it uses Link is irrelevant, what I am looking to find out is if there is somewhere within the API that allows you to do a replaceState instead of pushState to history. Reason being is I have actions that my users won't consider a new entry in their history, but that I want to be properly reflected in the URL.

Comment: Understood -- the goal being that if they navigate away and return it would remember their filter settings?

Comment: Precisely, and hit dead on the use case, presenting a list that the user modifies. Each modification shouldn't be a separate history entry, but is important.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88595/discussion-between-brad-bumbalough-and-matt).

Answer (score 1):

Specify `history` on your `contextTypes`, then call `this.context.history.replaceState`.

If you're using `React.createClass`, you can also use the `History` mixin.